# Background under icomoon icon, white "border" showing

Tags: html, css, svg, icons, icomoon

I want to put a white background under an icon font that has a transparent part, so that part will change color on hover:

[image]

I tried with border-radius and with clip path. But still the white outline is showing. Even tried to make a smaller background. Doesn't work:

My css:

```
.icon-tw-blue {
    color:white;
    border-radius:30px;
    transition: all 0.5s
        
}

.icon-tw-blue:hover {
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#6ab8f1;
    background-color:white;
  
}
```

HTML

```
<li class="li-social"> 
    <a aria-label="Site Twitter" href="https://twitter.com/test" target="_blank">
        <span class="icon-tw-blue" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Could you please share a working jsfiddle?

Comment: I am not sure what is expected result? For your reference, I have created a codepen. Please update the code and help us to give you a proper solution to the mentioned issue. https://codepen.io/berdejitendra/pen/xxqWbag